# Recreational Drugs in the Wizarding World

Tags: harry-potter

Knowing that there are some potions or magic that have drug-like *side effects* ([Liquid Luck](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Felix_Felicis), for example makes Harry seem positively high and the [Love Potion](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Love_Potion) makes Ron seem literally drunk [with love]), those effects are not the **main intention**.

Are there any example of *purely recreational* spells or potions that are used in the Potter Universe?

I'm also interested in any performance enhancers, memory spells or painkilling spells/potions that are abused by intentionally overdosing.

Comment: http://www.mtv.com/news/1608823/harry-potter-actor-jamie-waylett-arrested-on-drug-charges/

Comment: Highly similar to http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/22683/in-the-wizarding-world-is-garden-gnome-saliva-used-recreationaly

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There are quite a few substances, charms and plants seen in the Harry Potter universe that are analogous to drugs:

### The "**[Euphoria Elixir](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Elixir_to_Induce_Euphoria)"** mentioned in Half Blood Prince.

- The primary effect is to induce a state of '**inexplicable, irrational happiness**'.

> Cheered by this thought, Harry skimmed through his copy of Advanced
>   Potion-Making and found a heavily corrected Half-Blood Prince’s
>   version of An Elixir to Induce Euphoria, which seemed not only to meet
>   Slughorn’s instructions, but **which might (Harry’s heart leapt as the
>   thought struck him) put Slughorn into such a good mood that he would
>   be prepared to hand over that memory if Harry could persuade him to
>   taste some** …
>
> ‘Well, now, this looks absolutely wonderful,’ said Slughorn clapping
>   his hands together an hour and a half later, as he stared down into
>   the sunshine-yellow contents of Harry’s cauldron. ‘Euphoria, I take
>   it? And what’s that I smell? Mmmm … you’ve added just a sprig of
>   peppermint, haven’t you? Unorthodox, but what a stroke of inspiration,
>   Harry. Of course, that would tend to counterbalance **the occasional
>   side-effects of excessive singing and nose-tweaking** … I really don’t
>   know where you get these brainwaves, my boy … unless –’

### The "[Cheering Charm](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Cheering_Charm)" mentioned in Prisoner of Azkaban

- The primary effect is to '**make a person happy**' however, when overdone it can create a stupor and fits of hysterical laughter

> ‘She could’ve done with a Cheering Charm on her, too,’ said Ron, as
>   the class left for lunch, all grinning broadly – **the Cheering Charms
>   had left them with a feeling of great contentment**.
>
> [snip]
>
> Then, after a hasty lunch, it was straight back upstairs for the
>   Charms exam. Hermione had been right; Professor Flitwick did indeed
>   test them on Cheering Charms. **Harry slightly overdid his out of nerves
>   and Ron, who was partnering him, ended up in fits of hysterical
>   laughter** and had to be led away to a quiet room for an hour before he
>   was ready to perform the Charm himself.

### [Alihotsy](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Alihotsy), mentioned in Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them

- Mentioned in Fantastic Beasts, **Alihotsy** (also known as the Hyena tree) is described as a magical tree, the leaves of which can induce hysteria and uncontrollable laughter.

> The Glumbumble (northern Europe) is a grey, furry-bodied  flying
>   insect that produces melancholy-inducing treacle, **which is used as an
>   antidote to the hysteria produced by eating Alihotsy leaves**.

The Trading Card Game also suggests that the leaves can be brewed into a [draught](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Alihotsy_Draught) and that drinking it (or inhaling the fumes) will induce the same hysteria...

[image]

### [Billywig Stings](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Billywig), as mentioned in Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them

- The primary effect is **giddiness** and uncontrollable levitation

> Those who have been stung by a Billywig suffer giddiness followed by
>   levitation.  Generations of young Australian witches and wizards have
>   attempted to catch Billywigs and provoke them into stinging **in order
>   to enjoy these side effects**

### Giggle Water contains [Chuckle Extract](http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/harrypotter/images/d/d7/PinnocksGiggleWaterAd.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20161029073447).

- Its primary effect seems to be to induce uncontrollable laughter

[image]

Comment: No in-story pain pill addicts or study drugs?

Comment: @cde - I think that deserves a second question. Memory spells or pain-relief spells aren't 'recreational'

Comment: Could add http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Dancing_Feet_Spell for a fun ol' time!

Comment: Pain-relief ones would be less common in the wizarding world, especially if you can mend broken bones etc with a flick of your wand

Comment: Do they have negative side-effects on your health, withdrawal symptoms, and do they cause addiction? If neither, then they cannot really be compared to muggle drugs.

Comment: @vsz physical addiction vs psychological addiction. And some recreational drugs don't produce addiction or withdrawal in muggle world either.

Comment: @vsz - cde is spot-on. There are no muggle drugs that aren't addictive **to some people**. By extension, I think we can assume the same is true of all of the charms and potions above. http://web4health.info/en/answers/add-general-non-add.htm